# How to make /search/ without parameters not return a 404?

Tags: permalinks, search, 404-error

I have a search.php file in my theme that displays search results.

Search queries directed to `https://example.com/search/query/` display the search results correctly. WordPress natively supports this URL structure.

I would like to be able to browse directly to `https://example.com/search/` without adding a search query, and have it display my search.php file, but it returns a 404 error.

How can I make this page work?

Comment: `https://example.com/search/query/` is actual  `https://example.com?s=query` which is generated by wordpress permalink structure.

Comment: @GovindKumar Yes I know, but browsing to `https://example.com/?s=` does not return a 404 error, while `https://example.com/search/` does.

Comment: Answering this question requires knowledge of how that plugin works.

Comment: Actually, WordPress natively supports the `https://example.com/search/query/` structure. I have updated my question.

Comment: ok, I edited the question a bit for clarity, since plugin is not involved at all.

Answer (score 2):

The search rewrite rule only captures the pattern `search/(.+)/?$`. A request to `search/` matches the root pages rule, so WordPress tries to find a page with that slug. You could create a page at that location and load a template [via a filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy), or, you could add a rewrite rule that just does an empty search:

```
function wpd_empty_search_fix(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^search/$',
        'index.php?s=',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_empty_search_fix' );
```

Comment: That rewrite rule did not work for me. I guess I'll try creating the search page manually.

Comment: @Swen - visit the Settings > Permalinks page to flush rewrite rules. New rules aren't picked up until the option that stores them long-term is emptied and repopulated.